# Java can't read file except when in project root directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IDEA 14 to follow a simple Java tutorial (JDBC). As part of this, I am storing some configuration properties in a file called `jdbcTutorial.properties`. When I put this in the root directory of the project, I can read it with the following:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("jdbcTutorial.properties"));
```

However, as soon as I move it to any other directory in the project, I get the error `"No such file or directory"`. **This happens regardless of whether I specify a relative or absolute path:**

[image]

Maybe there are more standard ways to use config files, but I would really like to understand the behavior I am observing. Thanks for helping!

Comment: It says "FileNotFoundException: jdbcTutorial.properties" and not "FileNotFoundException: /Users/****/jdbcTutorial/resources/jdbcTutorial.properties". This means that the version you are executing is not the version you are displaying in the source window. Try a full clean and re-build.

Comment: Rebuilding and invalidating cache did not help, but I did make it work, although I only semi-understand. I was specifying a JAR artifact in the project structure. When I deleted it, I noticed that I was getting a different error, that a JAR was not found. So presumably when you hit "run" if you have a jar it executes that artifact rather than compiling and executing your source code. So I had to build that artifact again, then run, and it works (finds the file). I'll do some more reading about this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default root directory would be added to your project's build path. Since the directory in which you are putting the file is not added in your project's build path jvm is unable to find the file. You have two options:

1. Add the folder where you are putting your prop to build path.
2. Access the file with full path i.e. /home/user/workspace/....

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - I emphasized further above that this happens even with absolute path specified.

Answer (score 1):

When you build a project, IDEA takes the files in the resources directory and puts them in the executable jar. So to get an input stream from that file, you need to get it directly from inside the jar. Instead of FileInputStream, use

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("jdbcTutorial.properties")
```

Comment: I'll take a look, I think you are suggesting a superior approach, but I was curious why exactly the specific issue I saw had occurred. I think a JAR still _can_ read an external file which I was reading with FileInputStream. I think the error I was getting was because I had not re-built the JAR. The "run" feature gives you several options - to run from main method, or to run a JAR you had previously built. My old JAR did not contain the code change to look for the file in this new directory. When I rebuilt the JAR, or just ran from main, it worked fine. I will look more into your tips too!

Comment: Yes the jar can indeed read an external file. Your issue was that when IDEA runs the jar, the default directory is the project root directory, so it wasn't finding the file that was in the resources directory.

Answer (score 0):

When no path is supplied for a file, java assumes that this file is in the project's root folder. So the relative path "." always points to this folder. When the file is somewhere else, put the appropriate relative path before the path name, like "./files/configuration/jdbcTutorial.properties".

It work also when you put an absolute file path before the path name, like "C:/Users/Me/Documents/Java/workspace/thisProject/files/configuration/jdbcTutorial.properties".

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - I emphasized further above that this happens even with absolute path specified.

Comment: Execute System.out.println(new File("jdbcTutorial.properties").getAbsolutePath()); to find out where the system assumes the file is.

Comment: Maybe the drive specification ("C:" or "D:") at the beginning of the absolute file path is missing?

Comment: Nope, I'm on a mac

Comment: I see. OK, then place the line `System.out.println(new File("jdbcTutorial.properties").getAbsolutePath());` as the first line in main() to find out where the system assumes the file is.

Comment: ... but as Klitos writes below, he searches for this file not within the file system, but within the jar 'jdbcTutorial.jar'.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true. AFAIK, instances of File refer only to files or folders within the file system, but not within a jar file.